# Java: how to initialize String[]?

Tags: java, string, initialization

**Error**

```
% javac  StringTest.java 
StringTest.java:4: variable errorSoon might not have been initialized
        errorSoon[0] = "Error, why?";
```

**Code**

```
public class StringTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String[] errorSoon;
                errorSoon[0] = "Error, why?";
        }
}
```

Comment: Java 8 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47769801/1216775

Answer (score 425, accepted):

You need to [initialize](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/lang/arrays.html) `errorSoon`, as indicated by the error message, you have only [declared](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) it.

```
String[] errorSoon;                   // <--declared statement
String[] errorSoon = new String[100]; // <--initialized statement
```

You need to initialize the array so it can allocate the correct memory storage for the `String` elements *before* you can start setting the index.

If you *only* declare the array (as you did) there is no memory allocated for the `String` elements, but only a reference handle to `errorSoon`, and will throw an error when you try to initialize a variable at any index.

As a side note, you could also initialize the `String` array inside braces, `{ }` as so,

```
String[] errorSoon = {"Hello", "World"};
```

which is equivalent to

```
String[] errorSoon = new String[2];
errorSoon[0] = "Hello";
errorSoon[1] = "World";
```

Comment: It's a pitty that you can't use () to instantiate every String in your array with a default value. An array of 5 empty strings should be = new Array[5](""); instead of = {"","","","",""}.

Comment: Use a for loop.

Answer (score 184):

```
String[] args = new String[]{"firstarg", "secondarg", "thirdarg"};
```

Comment: Maybe not the exactly what the OPs question title suggests but i was trying to pass my string to a parameter that accepts String[] , this is the solution

Comment: Can't you ommit the new String btw? String[] output = {"","",""}; seems to work in my code.

Comment: If you have already initialized your array and you want to re-initialize it, you can't go `args = {"new","array"};`
You will have to  `args = new String[]{"new", "array"};`

Answer (score 33):

```
String[] errorSoon = { "foo", "bar" };
```

-- or --

```
String[] errorSoon = new String[2];
errorSoon[0] = "foo";
errorSoon[1] = "bar";
```

Answer (score 13):

In **Java 8** we can also make use of streams e.g.

```
String[] strings = Stream.of("First", "Second", "Third").toArray(String[]::new);
```

In case we already have a list of strings (`stringList`) then we can collect into string array as:

```
String[] strings = stringList.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 9):

I believe you just migrated from C++, Well in java you have to initialize a data type(other then primitive types and String is not a considered as a primitive type in java ) to use them as according to their specifications if you don't then its just like an empty reference variable (much like a pointer in the context of C++).

```
public class StringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] errorSoon = new String[100];
        errorSoon[0] = "Error, why?";
        //another approach would be direct initialization
        String[] errorsoon = {"Error , why?"};   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
String[] arr = {"foo", "bar"};
```

If you pass a string array to a method, do:

```
myFunc(arr);
```

or do:

```
myFunc(new String[] {"foo", "bar"});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
String[] errorSoon = new String[n];
```

With n being how many strings it needs to hold.

You can do that in the declaration, or do it without the String[] later on, so long as it's before you try use them.

Answer (score 2):

You can always write it like this

```
String[] errorSoon = {"Hello","World"};

For (int x=0;x<errorSoon.length;x++) // in this way u create a for     loop that would like display the elements which are inside the array     errorSoon.oh errorSoon.length is the same as errorSoon<2 

{
   System.out.println(" "+errorSoon[x]); // this will output those two     words, at the top hello and world at the bottom of hello.  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to initialize size and set empty value to array of Strings

```
String[] row = new String[size];
Arrays.fill(row, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

**String Declaration:**

```
String str;
```

**String Initialization**

```
String[] str=new String[3];//if we give string[2] will get Exception insted
str[0]="Tej";
str[1]="Good";
str[2]="Girl";

String str="SSN";
```

We can get individual character in String:

```
char chr=str.charAt(0);`//output will be S`
```

If I want to to get individual character Ascii value like this:

```
System.out.println((int)chr); //output:83
```

Now i want to convert Ascii value into Charecter/Symbol.

```
int n=(int)chr;
System.out.println((char)n);//output:S
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] string=new String[60];
System.out.println(string.length);
```

> it is initialization and getting the STRING LENGTH code in very simple way for beginners